# HTML5 Form with PHP email POST

Tags: php, html

My HTML5 form validates perfectly fine, however I would like to send the data inputs on submit. I followed some tutorials, and a basic tutorial worked, however I've now tried a more complex PHP script to send the email and I dont get sent anything??

```
<?php
// Subject and Email Variables

$emailSubject = 'HTML5 Form Submission';
$webMaster = 'John.Doe@live.co.uk';

//Gathering Data variables

$FNameField = $_POST['FName'];
$LNameField = $_POST['LName'];
$ageField = $_POST['age'];
$emailField = $_POST['EMail'];
$URLField = $_POST['URL'];
$telField = $_POST['tel'];
$messageField = $_POST['message'];

$body = <<<EOD
<br><hr><br>
Name: $FNameField<br>
Age: $ageField <br>
Email: $emailField <br>
Website: $URLField <br>
Telephone: $telField <br>
Message: $messageField <br>
EOD;

    $headers = "From: $email\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html\r\n";
    $success = mail($webMaster, $emailSubject, $body, $headers);

    $theResults = <<<EOD

<html>
<head>
<title>JakesWorks - travel made easy-Homepage</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-style: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #666666;
    text-decoration: none;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<div>
  <div align="left">Thank you for your interest! Your email will be answered very soon!</div>
</div>
<div>
<a href="Forms.php">Click Here to return to the previous page</a>
</body>
</html>
EOD;

echo "$theResults";




?>
```

EDIT: It is also web hosted, so there's no issue there and my server does understand PHP

Comment: Do you get any error? Where is the problem you facing?

Comment: No error, the web page outputs as normal
I just dont recieve the email displaying the contents of the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing gmail accepts the message, we know it is not a server error.

In my experiences, there are many ways that you can make this be able to be sent the a live account, the number one being your headers.

**To get my webform to send (and be accepted) to most email accounts, I used these headers:**

```
$headers = 'From: Example Last <noreply@example.com>' . "\r\n"; // Set from headers
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
```

Notice the From header, it has a capital "name" followed by a a space. After the space, there is an email related to the website it was sent from. In your case, I'd say the email should be "`<noreply@mattmeadows.info>`".

Now, the emails verify that proper html email is sent out to you, which include the `<html>` and `<body>` tags. Since it's easier to send a plain text and you have no need for it to look fancy (since it's being sent to you), you can set the header to a plain text email.

Then you would have to make `$body` as follows:

```
$body = "Name: $FNameField
Age: $ageField
Email: $emailField
Website: $URLField
Telephone: $telField
Message: $messageField";
```

*To conclude, the answer to your question is:* **The live mail servers are rejecting your php mail form.** You can make the following changes and it should be able to mail all emails.

Comment: That is a good comment, don't use assume that it goes successfully, there's no point in assigning a variable for it anyways if It's not going to be used. Add exceptions to the code, your system will break in one way or another otherwise, @user1860423

Comment: I've aded those lines to my code and it still directs to the HTML page as it should do, but I still recieve no email with the content :(

Comment: Do me a favor, change the email to "hackywackee@gmail.com" and try to send an email.

Comment: It appears to be working now!

1 more question, what is the correct way to insert a line break, as in a space between each content line that is emailed?

Also, how do I set it so it displays the first and last name values in the from section, as at the moment all i get is (unknown)

Comment: I have edited to be the exact reason why your mail wasn't being received before.

Comment: Well, the reason for my header containing emailField was so that it would display the email address entered in the form, not a message to be sent out to other users

Comment: Which is usually not allowed because spammers and phishers change emails, usually you wanna user an email from your domain.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you've defined

```
ini_set("SMTP","smtp.example.com" ); 
ini_set('sendmail_from', 'user@example.com');
```

Or just do it in the ini file.

And please don't forget the enter and the backslash in the break markups.